# Why all the elements of the queue are the same, elements are added to the queue in the posix thread

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, queue, mutex

There is such a code. There is a global queue and in the posix thread you add new elements, but when, after the addition of all, I print to screen queue, it turns out that all the elements are the same

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>

std::queue<int> q;
pthread_mutex_t set_queue_mutex;

void* producer(void*)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t m = rand() % 100 + 1;
    usleep(m/1000);
    size_t n = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int s = q.size();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&set_queue_mutex);
    q.push(n);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&set_queue_mutex);
}
int main(int c, char** v)
{
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;

    ///* Usage */
    if(c == 3)
    {
        n = atoi(v[1]);
        m = atoi(v[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong count of parameters, see usage: test $1 $2" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    pthread_t* t1 = new pthread_t[n];
    assert(t1 != 0);
    pthread_t* t2 = new pthread_t[m];
    assert(t2 != 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&t1[i], 0, &producer, 0);
        pthread_join(t1[i], 0);
    }

    while(q.size() != 0)
    {
        std::cout << q.front() << std::endl;
        q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for example --- ./main 3 3 
and displayed on the screen -----     16
                                      16
                                      16

My threads are synchronized using mutexes, why is it ?

Comment: Your program is still sequential, as `pthread_join` *blocks* until the thread is done. So your program creates one thread, the *waits* for it to finish before starting the next thread, and so on.

Comment: You should probably `join` in a separate loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `srand()` every time. Move the call to `main`. Otherwise the value is supposed to change only on seconds boundaries.

Comment: I check in GDB,  each time is generated is different value, so I think the problem here is not srand

Comment: Probably with `gdb` it's slower. Have you tried moving `srand` call to main? I have.